# Android sourceSets is there a way to use nested flavor structure?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

Is there a way to use nested flavor structure inside sourceSets? the example bellow kinda works, although when building appleJuice res from orange.juice also included and overrides some of the appleJuice res values.

```
   productFlavors {
        apple {
            dimension "fruit"
        }
        orange {
            dimension "fruit"
        }
        juice {
            dimension "beverage"
        }
        tea {
            dimension "beverage"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        apple {
            juice {
                res.srcDirs = ["src/apple/juice/res"]
            }
            tea {
                res.srcDirs = ["src/apple/juice/res"]
            }
        }
        orange {
            juice {
                res.srcDirs = ["src/orange/juice/res"]
            }
            tea {
                res.srcDirs = ["src/orange/tea/res"]
            }
        }
    }
```